# How to create a new file if doens't exist and write to it?

Tags: php

I need to read a url, get its content, then check on the server if a JS file exists, if not insert that content within a js var on the newely created file and save the file with today dates.

I tried this but it is not writing any file:

```
$today = date("n-j-y");
$url = "https://example.com/data.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$fp = fopen($today."_us_states.js", 'w');
fwrite($fp, "var data =" . $json.";");
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using `fopen` in `w` mode is the correct way to do that. You may be experiencing some permission issues, possibly, when attempting to create the file. Be sure to check the return value of `fopen()` before proceeding to write to the file and check your error logs for details.

As a side note you can more succinctly do this with `file_put_contents` in one call instead of `fopen` + `fwrite` + `fclose` combination,  as `file_put_contents` does all three in one.

```
$today = date("n-j-y");
$url = "https://example.com/data.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents("$today_us_states.js", "var data = $json");
```

Comment: I was using file_put_contents("$today_us_states.js", "var data = $json"); only but it was not creating a new file but writing to the existing one

Comment: I guess I don't have permissions and I don't know how to change it to a specific folder in bitnami wordpress on lightsail, tried to run all bash commands I have found but not luck